# Python with sqlalchemy db retrival

Tags: python, sql, network-programming, sqlalchemy

I am quite new to python and to sqlalchemy.I have written the following netowrk program.

```
class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address
        self.port_no     = port_no
```

#

```
def act_like_switch (self, packet, packet_in):
    """
    Implement switch-like behavior.
    """
    # Learn the port for the source MAC
    print "RECIEVED FROM PORT ",packet_in.in_port , "SOURCE ",packet.src
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    self.mac_to_port[packet.src]=packet_in.in_port
    if(self.matrix.get((packet.src,packet.dst))==None):
            # create a Session
            #print "creating a db session"
            #Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            #session = Session()        
            self.matrix[(packet.src,packet.dst)]=0
            # Create an entry with address and port
            print "creating a new db entry"
            entry = SourcetoPort(src_address="packet.src" , port_no=packet_in.in_port)
            # Add the record to the session object
            session.add(entry)
            session.commit()
    self.matrix[(packet.src,packet.dst)]+=1
    #if self.mac_to_port.get(packet.dst)!=None:
    if session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=packet.dst).all():
      #send this packet
      self.send_packet(packet_in.buffer_id, packet_in.data,self.mac_to_port[packet.dst], packet_in.in_port)
      #create a flow modification message
      msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
      #set the fields to match from the incoming packet
      msg.match = of.ofp_match.from_packet(packet)

      #print "SENDING  TO PORT " + str(self.mac_to_port[packet.dst]), packet.dst
      # send the rule to the switch so that it does not query the controller again.
      msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=self.mac_to_port[packet.dst]))
      # push the rule
      self.connection.send(msg)

    else:
      #print 'flooding the packet '
      # Flood this packet out as we don't know about this node.
      self.send_packet(packet_in.buffer_id, packet_in.data,
                       of.OFPP_FLOOD, packet_in.in_port)
```

In the above code the line

```
if session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address='packet.dst').all():
```

does not work as I expect it.What I expect is that it should retrive the entry from sqlalchemy database and if it succeeds (as the output is not NONE) it should execute the following code.

When I try to print that line using print

```
 print "session query", session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address='packet.dst').all()
```

The output that I get is

```
session query  []
```

Am I doing something wrong.It would be great if someone could point this out.

If I change the above line based on the suggestion as

```
print session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=packet.dst).count()
```

I get the following error:

```
creating a new db entry
RECIEVED FROM PORT  2 SOURCE  96:74:ba:a9:92:b9
creating a new db entry

ERROR:core:Exception while handling Connection!PacketIn...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ws_thesis/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 234, in raiseEventNoErrors
    return self.raiseEvent(event, *args, **kw)
  File "ws_thesis/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 281, in raiseEvent
    rv = event._invoke(handler, *args, **kw)
  File "ws_thesis/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 159, in _invoke
    return handler(self, *args, **kw)
  File "ws_thesis/pox/tutorial.py", line 137, in _handle_PacketIn
    self.act_like_switch(packet, packet_in)
  File "ws_thesis/pox/tutorial.py", line 101, in act_like_switch
    print session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=packet.dst).count()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2400, in count
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2045, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2014, in one
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2057, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2072, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in execute
```

Comment: My apologies about the '==' claims, I got confused with the direct column reference syntax over the keyword syntax. Your traceback is still incomplete. What *is* the value of `packet.dst` and is it *compatible* with your column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter items by the contents of a *variable*, you need to use that variable directly:

```
session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=packet.dst)
```

You were instead trying to filter by the string `'packet.dst'`.

You made the same mistake when *creating* the `SourcetoPort` entry; you probably wanted to store result of the `packet.src` expression, not the string `'packet.src'`:

```
SourcetoPort(src_address=packet.src, port_no=packet_in.in_port)
```

Note that calling `.all()` retrieves all matching entries from the database, but you are only using it in a `if` test. It would be more efficient (potentially *much* more so) to use `.count()` instead of `.all()` to let the database tell us how many items match:

```
if session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=packet.dst).count():
```